# custom \newenvironment{pullquote} not working

Tags: environments, pullquote, define

I’m trying to define a custom `\newenvironment` for a pull quote. Without the `environment` it goes as follows and works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%%%pullquote%%%%
\definecolor{colorquote}{HTML}{e8e9f5}
\newtcolorbox{myquote{colback=colorquote,colframe=colorquote,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt}


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertxnames=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[notes,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex-chicago}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}



\addbibresource{}
\author{}
\title{\color[RGB]{40,39,129,255}\textbf{Title}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}
            content for pull quote
        \end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum*[3]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I try to create the `\newenvironment` it gives out that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}



%%%%%section fonts%%%%
\sectionfont{\color[HTML]{282781}}
\subsectionfont{\color[HTML]{282781}}

%%%%pullquote%%%%
\definecolor{colorquote}{HTML}{e8e9f5}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=colorquote, colframe=colorquote,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt}

\newenvironment{pullquote}
    {\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}
        \end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    }


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[notes,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex-chicago}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}



\addbibresource{}
\author{Louis Vigneras}
\title{\color[RGB]{40,39,129,255}\textbf{Title}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
\lipsum[1]

\begin{pullquote}
    content for pull quote.
\end{pullquote}

\lipsum*[3]
    
\end{document}
```

P.S. I’m leaving the other packages in case it is a question of package conflict.

Comment: you have no end code specified (it is taking the blank line as `\par` as the missing argument) so the content of `pullquote` is after `\end{wrapfig}` but `wrapfig` can not be inside a group so you can not easily use it in an environment definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{pullquote}
    {\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}
        \end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    }
```

Is

```
\newenvironment{pullquote}
    {\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}
        \end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    }
    {\par}
```

so

```
\begin{pullquote}
    content for pull quote.
\end{pullquote}
```

is

```
 \begingroup
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}
        \end{myquote}
\end{wrapfigure}
content for pull quote.
\par
\endgroup
```

with `wrapfigure` empty.

you intended

```
\newenvironment{pullquote}
    {\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
        \begin{myquote}%
    }
    {%
    \end{myquote}
    \end{wrapfigure}%
    }
```

so the content of the enviroment goes inside the wrapfig.
But `wrapfig` needs to adjust the shape of a following paragraph so can not be in a group such as an environment so it is easier to use a command

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}



%%%%%section fonts%%%%
\sectionfont{\color[HTML]{282781}}
\subsectionfont{\color[HTML]{282781}}

%%%%pullquote%%%%
\definecolor{colorquote}{HTML}{e8e9f5}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=colorquote, colframe=colorquote,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt}

\newcommand\pullquote[1]{%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}%
        \begin{myquote}%
         #1%
        \end{myquote}%
    \end{wrapfigure}}



\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[notes,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex-chicago}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}



\addbibresource{}
\author{Louis Vigneras}
\title{\color[RGB]{40,39,129,255}\textbf{Title}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
\lipsum[1]

\pullquote{content for pull quote.}

\lipsum*[3]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm. However, I don’t understand why with `wrapfig` wouldn’t work in an environment and that it has to be a `\newcommand` instead. Could you point me in the right direction to understand (documentation, thread, etc.)?

Comment: @Louis.vgn wrapfig.sty says: `- If you put a wrapfigure in a parbox or a minipage, or any other type of grouping, the text wrapping should end before the group does.`  you had it in an envronment so the group ended before the text had started.

Comment: Ok I see now, thanks.